# Apple Notes alternative for Samsung device

Tags: samsung, sync, notes

I am looking for an free and ad-free solution which is comparable to Apple Notes, which I used some years ago on an iPad.

I want to be able to take simple plain-text notes, and access them both on a computer (on OS X) and on a Samsung S7. I don't need fancy features (Evernote-like), in fact I much prefer simplicity.

The Memo app that comes with the phone is perfectly sufficient for my needs, and looks like *just what I want*. Except there's one big problem: I can't figure out how to access the notes on a computer.  Syncing with "Samsung Cloud" is turned on for Memo in the settings.

I don't expect to be able to find a third-party app that provides such functionality for free, as whoever provides the service will need to pay for server costs.  But I did expect Samsung to provide such functionality, given that Apple has had it for a long time ...

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. You want a free solution, but you don't expect to be able to find one. You have an app that doesn't have the feature you need, and you find that Evernote does have the feature you need, but you don't want to use Evernote because it has too many features. What is your actual question?

Comment: @DanHulme I am looking for a solution that fulfils my criteria. I am not sure if the Memo app can do what I want. It *seems* it cannot, but I am not sure. If an answer shows how I can use it, I will accept that.  I found some articles suggesting that older versions could synchronize, but I can't get the one in my phone to do that.  I prefer simple solutions, but if only complex programs are available, I will accept that too. To my knowledge, Evernote is not free (or the free version doesn't fit my criteria), so I did not consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say 'Google Keep' is one of the best ones to use:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you the gratis app DejaOffice, besides the Notes/memos app, there is task and calendar included in the suite.
http://dejaoffice.com/

As there are android and iOS version you can move the data in the future to the other platform

As standalone app (data stored in phone) it is free/gratis.However it also has paid functions such as sync with their own cloud or sync with different desktop PIM apps as Outlook.